# using covariance on an interface ...Runtime Error Unable to cast object of type 'derviedAService ' to type 'iBaseService`1[mybase]'

Tags: c#, generics, interface

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace mymodels
{
public abstract class mybase
{
     public string v1 {get; set;}
}     


public class derivedA : mybase
{
      public string v2 {get; set;}
}


public class derivedB : mybase
{
      public string v2 {get; set;}
}

} 


namespace myservices 
{
interface iBaseService<T>  where T : mymodels.mybase
{
    T   Get ();
}



public class derviedAService : iBaseService<mymodels.derivedA>
{
    public derviedAService (){}

    public mymodels.derivedA Get()
    {
        mymodels.derivedA d = new mymodels.derivedA();

        return d;
    }
}   


public class derviedBService : iBaseService<mymodels.derivedB>
{
    public derviedBService (){}

    public mymodels.derivedB Get()
    {
        mymodels.derivedB d = new mymodels.derivedB();

        return d;
    }
}
}


namespace m
{
public class user
{

    myservices.iBaseService<mymodels.mybase> myservice = null;


    public user()
    {
        bool mode1 = true;

        if (mode1)
            myservice = (myservices.iBaseService<mymodels.mybase>)new myservices.derviedAService();
        else
            myservice = (myservices.iBaseService<mymodels.mybase>)new myservices.derviedBService();
    }   

}   
}
```

I am trying to create a generic interface for a service that uses an abstract base class and derived classes.   From the generic interface I am creating two implementations, one for each derived type.  I have this setup, with out any problems....

My problem comes in my usage class..... For now I am trying to avoid using an IOC (unity, etc...) I wanted to setup the usage class to create an instance of the base service class and then type cast the instance to the selected derivedservice implementation ...

I believe this can be done with unity.... which I plan to use eventually... but for now I just wanted to do something simple to get up and running...  My code compiles but at run time I get an error in the following pattern:

Unable to cast object of type 'derviedAService ' to type 'iBaseService`1[mybase]'.

I have tried to use an interface in place of the abstract class and this did not solve the problem.

Comment: It would really help if you would format your code more readably in questions - and also give *minimal* examples. You really don't need 83 lines of code to demonstrate this. Also, even if you personally don't follow .NET naming conventions normally (and I'd strongly recommend that you start doing so) it's worth doing so for sample code like this - you should make it as easy as possible for *us* to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface isn't covariant - it needs to be explicitly covariant when you declare it. So this:

```
interface iBaseService<T>  where T : mymodels.mybase
```

should be:

```
interface iBaseService<out T>  where T : mymodels.mybase
```

... except that you should *also* follow .NET naming conventions, using PascalCase for namespace, type and method names. Your code is *very* unconventional at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the code....next time I will spend more time on naming ... However you solution is correct ... This is what was missing and the code now works.   Thank you.